# Android SharedPreferences Concurrency

Tags: android, concurrency, sharedpreferences

I am writing a date to SharedPreferences when ever my app retrieves the latest data from a feed. I now need to read that value however I cannot find much information on concurrency when reading/writing to SharedPreferences.

Would I have to use the synchronized keyword in my methods to prevent/lower the chances of causing a force close? Or have the folks at Google made SharedPreferences in a way that I shouldn't worry about this?

For the record I do not think there is much likelihood of a collision due to the infrequent read and write operations although I would not like to assume that everything will just "work".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the flag [MODE_MULTI_PROCESS](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#MODE_MULTI_PROCESS) when opening the SharedPreferences. This was the legacy (but undocumented) behavior in and before Gingerbread (Android 2.3) and this flag is implied when targeting such releases. For applications targeting SDK versions greater than Android 2.3, this flag must be explicitly set if desired.

**This constant was deprecated in API level 23.**
`MODE_MULTI_PROCESS` does not work reliably in some versions of Android, and furthermore does not provide any mechanism for reconciling concurrent modifications across processes. Applications should not attempt to use it. Instead, they should use an explicit cross-process data management approach such as [`ContentProvider`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentProvider.html).

Comment: This flag is only useful when the same SharedPreferences is used across multiple process, however it doesn't do anything particular running in the same process.

Answer (score 1):

As per [android doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html).

Note:currently this class does not support use across multiple processes. This will be added later.

So, If you are worried about multi-threaded access to shared preferences, you need to synchronize.

Comment: Synchronizing is unnecessary as long as the SharedPreferences is used inside a single process, multi-threaded or not. However there might be an issue when used across multiple processes. While a process is writing the preference to 'disk', any other process attempting to read it will fail and get a clean/empty SharedPreferences, similar to the one after installation.

Comment: @3c71 I am running into this very problem when concurrently accessing a sharedPreferences between my UI and Service, which run in different processes. How might I go about "synchronizing" the calls across processes?

Comment: @Flyview: I would suggest "ask new question", you may use this question as reference in your new question (and) accepted question has answer for your question. If you tried that approach but didn't work, put what you tried in new question.

Comment: The reason the file is deleted is this:

commit() will create a backup file while executing SharedPrefs.writeToFile(). If the master file is successfully written, the backup file will be deleted. However, if Process2 runs SharedPrefs.loadFromDiskLocked() (e.g. because you open the prefs multiprocess) it will check if there is a backup file. If it exists, the master file will be deleted and the backup file will be renamed to the master file. If you're really unlucky, Process2 sees the backup file and deletes master, but Process1's writeToFile will delete it before it has been renamed.